# failed to submit supervisor: request failed with status code 500. Apache kafka to druid

Tags: apache-kafka, druid

I want to upload my data from kafka server to druid.
At first it success to load the data through the following [tutorial](https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/tutorials/tutorial-kafka.html) of druid documentation.

But at last step in submit data, it's failed the error pop up in windows that say 'failed to submit supervisor: request failed with status code 500'

This is the supervisor created at last step in druid server

```
{
  "type": "kafka",
  "spec": {
    "ioConfig": {
      "type": "kafka",
      "consumerProperties": {
        "bootstrap.servers": "localhost:9092"
      },
      "topic": "t6",
      "inputFormat": {
        "type": "json"
      },
      "useEarliestOffset": true,
      "appendToExisting": false
    },
    "tuningConfig": {
      "type": "kafka"
    },
    "dataSchema": {
      "dataSource": "t6",
      "granularitySpec": {
        "type": "uniform",
        "queryGranularity": "NONE",
        "segmentGranularity": "HOUR",
        "rollup": false
      },
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "!!!_no_such_column_!!!",
        "missingValue": "2010-01-01T00:00:00Z"
      },
      "dimensionsSpec": {
        "dimensions": [
          {
            "type": "long",
            "name": "jumlah_pembelian"
          },
          "kode_cabang",
          "kode_item",
          "kode_kasir",
          "kode_produk",
          {
            "name": "tgl_transaksi",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

How can I solve this case?
Thank in advance
Before i ran druid server, i also ran kafka server that might crash each other zookeeper server

Comment: Do you know the 500 http error code?

Comment: i dont know about this error message. i have searched it in internet but get nothing

Comment: In general, 500 means internal server error - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes. Which means there's a problem in the server side (internal error). tryo to debug this specific server and understand what cause this error. hope it helps

Comment: _might crash each other zookeeper server_ ... You do not need separate Zookeeper servers